# How to refresh headers with token for fullcalendar AJAX requests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fullcalendar

I'm sending token headers under eventSources option for "full calender" with below headers option in Angular:

```
eventSources: [
    {
        url: '/api/schedules',
        headers: JSON.parse($cookies['auth_headers']),
        error: function () {
            var $state = $injector.get('$state');
            $state.transitionTo('page.login');
        }
    }
],
```

Given fullcalendar uses jQuery, I need to have headers refreshed for every request. Is there a way to do this with fullcalendar?

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but specifying a `beforeSend` function should make this possible:

```
eventSources: [
    {
        url: '/api/schedules',
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            var headers = JSON.parse($cookies['auth_headers']);
            for (var i in headers ) xhr.setRequestHeader(i, headers[i]);
        },
        error: function () {
            var $state = $injector.get('$state');
            $state.transitionTo('page.login');
        }
    }
],
```

Comment: Is thie an option in fullcalendar?

Comment: I updated my code to show it in use. Fullcalendar is supposed to expose all the options available to `$.ajax`